# HTTP POST convert @ to %40

Tags: java, httpclient

```
URI uri = new  URIBuilder()
            .setScheme("https")
            .setHost("1.1.1.1")
            .setPath("/cgi-bin/login")
            .setParameter("username", name)
            .build();
...
CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

The "name"  would be  an email address. The symbol @ will　be converted to "%40" when HTTP　post.  what's the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: how to avoid this converting? thanks

Comment: Is this converting creates any roblem for you..I guess you can always decode string at server

Comment: It's supposed to work this way.

Comment: @KevinPanko According to the [URI RFC](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986), the `@` character is a valid character in the URI query part.

Comment: "Server" is not mime. It don't acknowledge %40, so i have to submit @ not %40.

Comment: @Ron - Is name coming with with an `@` symbol or is it being converted ahead of the method?

Comment: @ProfessionalAmateur It comes in with a `@`.

Comment: It comes in with a @. i use a normal email, e.g. tom@yahoo.com as the parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I consider that a bug with the Apache HTTP client library. The [URI specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) states that the character `@` in the URI query is perfectly valid and doesn't require encoding.

If you are willing to branch out to another library, you can use Spring Web's `UriComponents` and `UriComponentsBuilder`.

```
UriComponents components = UriComponentsBuilder.newInstance()
                            .scheme("https")
                            .host("1.1.1.1")
                            .path("/cgi-bin/login")
                            .queryParam("name", "test@email.com").build();
URI uri = components.toUri();
System.out.println(uri);
```

prints

```
https://1.1.1.1/cgi-bin/login?name=test@email.com
```

Spring, here, lets the `URI` class do its own encoding in its constructor.